# suitable image found ; xcode 13.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

After installing AdMob with CocoaPods in iOS, the same error is repeated continuously during app installation.

This only occurs when building on the iPhone and does not occur in the simulator.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/DDday
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C855177-A56F-404D-87E0-21273F9473EE/DDday.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: Use the paid account to solve this problem instead of the apple's personal provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue introduced with iOS 13.3.1. Hopefully Apple is working on a permanent fix.

To work-around try the following steps, they worked for me when experiencing the same issue:

1. Open your Podfile and replace the "use_frameworks!" line with "use_modular_headers!"
2. In Terminal execute `pod update && pod install`
3. In Xcode clean the build folder and re-run the project.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with iOS 13.3.1. All dynamic frameworks being compiled to the newest release of iOS 13.3.1 are experiencing this issue when running on a personal provisioning profile/developer account.

You can:

Use a non-Personal Team provisioning profile (**paid developer account**).
Run on the 13.3.1 simulator.
Test on a real iOS device running 13.3 or lower.
Hopefully this issue will be fixed soon.